# Using jQuery to select row from table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a HTML table as outlined below (with sample data):

```
<table class="tbl">
  <caption>Version History Table</caption>

  <thead>   
    <tr>
      <th>Change Date</th>
      <th>Change Type</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>StaffID</th>
    </tr>   
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>16/04/2010 07:30</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>New role</td>
      <td>00215</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15/02/2012 14:37</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>Out of stock</td>
      <td>85487</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14/03/2013 10:18</td>
      <td>Add</td>
      <td>Out of date</td>
      <td>15748</td>
    </tr>              
  </tbody>

</table>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a user selects a row a pop-up/dialog box appears showing details of the history.

Comment: How do they "select a row"?

Answer (score 9):

With a little jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

And some CSS...

```
table tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can accomplish your requirement

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beyym/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('tr', 'table.tbl tbody').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Edit:- Based on your comment, you dont need to put onClick in all trs. you can use Jquery selectors to assign click event to all your trs

With your showDialog method you can do this and inside showDIalog , this will be the clicked `tr`.

```
$('tr', 'table.tbl tbody').click(showDialog);
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i know i should read around the topic first, which i've done. I have assigned each <tr> an onClick class, for example, <tr onClick="showDialog()"> which calls my showDialog function.. I just wanted sure if this was the best option.

Comment: Ok. Please see my update and see if that helps. This will reduce using onclick="showdialog" in all trs.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the table using, for example, a **tag** like **p** or something else to identify a column that's a key on your context

```
    <table class="tbl">
    <caption>Version History Table</caption>

    <thead>   
        <tr>
        <th>Change Date</th>
        <th>Change Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>StaffID</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>16/04/2010 07:30</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>New role</td>
        <td><p>00215</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>15/02/2012 14:37</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Out of stock</td>
        <td><p>85487</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>14/03/2013 10:18</td>
        <td>Add</td>
        <td>Out of date</td>
        <td><p>15748</p></td>
        </tr>              
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Picked row:</p>
    <p id="linea"></p>
    <p>The key for the row picked (StaffID) was:</p>
    <p id="StaffID"></p>
```

You can extract the key of the choosen row also using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
        $("#linea").text($(this).text())
        $("#StaffID").text($(this).children('td').children('p').text())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will show the details as mentioned in the question.

[image: Snapshot attached]

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.tbl tbody tr').click(function () {
        var details = '';
        details += 'Change Date : ' + $(this).find('td:first-child').html() + '\n';
        details += 'Change Type : ' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html() + '\n';
        details += 'Description : ' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').html() + '\n';
        details += 'StaffID : ' + $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').html() + '\n';
            alert(details);
      });
    });
  </script>
```